# adding ui-upload to angular-fullstack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-fullstack

**the problem:**
properly adding ui-upload to an **angular-fullstack** project. Added the same as ui-router, but not finding it?

**The error:**
*Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module niaFrontendApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module {} due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'module' is not a function, got Object*

**app.ts:**

```js
const angular = require('angular');
const ngCookies = require('angular-cookies');
const ngResource = require('angular-resource');
const ngSanitize = require('angular-sanitize');
const ngAnimate = require('angular-animate');
const uiRouter = require('angular-ui-router');
const uiBootstrap = require('angular-ui-bootstrap');
const uiUploader = require('angular-ui-uploader');
...
angular.module('niaFrontendApp', [
  ngCookies,
  ngResource,
  ngSanitize,
  ngAnimate,

  uiRouter,
  uiBootstrap,
  uiUploader,
...
```